ITMS-91056: Invalid privacy manifest
App Store Connect
Hello,
We noticed one or more issues with a recent submission for App Store review for the following app:
Qizlar Akademiyasi
Version 1.4.4
Build 13
Please correct the following issues and upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-91056: Invalid privacy manifest - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file from the following path is invalid: “Frameworks/Reachability.framework/ReachabilitySwift.bundle/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy”. Keys and values in your app’s privacy manifests must be valid. For more details about privacy manifest files, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files.
Apple Developer Relations
I added to infoPlist to this but I think its not working
<!-- Location Permissions -->
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need location when in use</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Always and when in use!</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Older devices need location.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can I have location always?</string>

<!-- Media Library Permissions -->
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>Music!</string>
<key>kTCCServiceMediaLibrary</key>
<string>media</string>

<!-- Calendar Permissions -->
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Calendars</string>
<key>NSCalendarsFullAccessUsageDescription</key>
<string>Calendar full access</string>

<!-- Camera Permission -->
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Camera access required</string>

<!-- Contacts Permission -->
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Contacts access required</string>

<!-- Microphone Permission -->
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Microphone access required</string>

<!-- Speech Recognition Permission -->
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>Speech recognition required</string>

<!-- Motion Sensors Permission -->
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>Motion detection access required</string>

<!-- Photo Library Permission -->
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo library access required</string>

<!-- Reminder Permission -->
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>Reminders access required</string>

<!-- Bluetooth Permission -->
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Bluetooth always access required</string>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>Bluetooth peripheral access required</string>


<!-- Siri Permission -->
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to Siri Kit is required</string>


Reading the issue closely, you can see that Apple says there is an issue in ReachabilitySwift.
Probably updating that library should fix your issue. If that library is kept up to date, the latest version of the library should include a valid privacy manifest file.

cd ios
pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
flutter clean
flutter build ios

Yes! I also faced this problem. I searched a lot but did not find any solution. Then I searched a bit on YouTube and Google and found the solution.
I Share you step by step solution.

Frist you create archive file.
Then Right click Archive file. and select  "Generate privacy report " save you laptop.
Then open download file and see missing file in bottom.
Then search you missing privacy you project folder (PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy) like ReachabilitySwift
Then Open Privacy Source code and copy past other success privacy and edit acording.


Like This


cd ios
pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
flutter clean
flutter build ios

it works

Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
